# Unitary operator acting on a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, operator-theory

If $U(t)$ and $U^0(t)$ are unitary operators, $|\psi⟩$ and $|\phi⟩$ two vectors and we have the limit between these vectors below as follows

$\lim_{t \to -\infty} ∥U(t) |\psi⟩ - U^0(t)|\phi⟩∥=0$.

How do I go from the above equation to the following equation

$\lim_{t \to -\infty} ∥ |\psi⟩ - U^{\dagger}(t)U^0(t)|\phi⟩∥=0$.

I think I just take the square root of $U^{\dagger}(t)$ and multiply the first expression by that. Is my reasoning right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unitary implies $U^{\dagger}(t) U(t) = I$, where $I$ is the identity operator. Hence, just multiply both sides by $U^{\dagger}$ on the left and distribute by linearity. You are allowed to absorb $U^{\dagger}$ into the norm since unitary operations preserve norms. I.e.
$$
\|U(t) \psi - U^0 (t) \phi \| = x, \\
\|\psi  - U^{\dagger}(t)U^0 (t)\phi\| = \|U^{\dagger}(t)\| x.
$$
Note that $x \to 0$ as $t \to -\infty$, and since $U^{\dagger}(t)$ is bounded (Unitary operators are bounded) , we get $\|U^{\dagger}(t)\| x \to 0$ as well.

Also note that one can prove the reverse direction by the same argument.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply the expression on the left by the inverse of $U$, $U^{-1} = U^{\dagger}$ and use linearity.